# Devise reset password link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I' have some apllication on production server. I'm using devise. I have problem because when user want to change  password he got's email with link but link has the localhost:3000 and it is not working. How can I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In config/environments you need to set the default url for the action mailer to use

For example

config/environments/production.erb

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'production.url.com' }
```

Comment: I have another problem. When users got message for reset password it is from: "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com".
I change in initializers/devise.rb config.mailer_sender = "Test" but it still not working

Comment: This is the correct place to put it, make sure you have restarted your rails server? Any other problems I would open a new question.